# Alternative Location for Silverlight_SDK

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, sdk

There seems to be a browser hijack problem and I really dont have time to sort it. I need an alternative download location for Silverlight SDK 3 since microsoft.com does not work.

Comment: Where's the programming question in here?...

Comment: there will be programming questions once I get the SDK :P

Comment: So I looked and there weren't any SDK question in almost a year from when you asked this question.

Answer (score 0):

you will find here

http://www.softpedia.com/get/Internet/WEB-Design/Flash/Microsoft-Silverlight-SDK.shtml

Comment: its not a mirror, just has links to microsoft site